# DataView.RowFilter and "N2" formatted numbers - how to achieve "what you see is what you filter"?

Tags: c#, formatting, filtering, dataview, rowfilter

I have a column of decimal numbers, which are displayed using `N2` formatting. This means that the number 12000.4656887 will be shown as `12,000.47`:

[image]

At the same time, I have a textbox where the user can enter text, and I set a `DataView.RowFilter` according to the user-specified filter. The problem is that the user sees the number `12,000.47`, and he types `12,000.47`, but of course, he sees nothing because the number is actually `12000.4656887`.

[image]

This is a bug from the user's perspective. So I need to filter according to the textual representation, not according to the underlying value. At the same time I don't want to change the underlying values in the DataTable.

I tried using something like `view.RowFilter = "Convert([number], System.String, 'N2') LIKE '12,000.47'";`, but it didn't work - it just throws an exception `Invalid number of arguments: function Convert()`, which means that `Convert` doesn't accept a formatting parameter. 
Also, I can't fix it by changing the filter value, because that would require to "un-round" it from `12000.47` to `12000.4656887`. The only way would be round the values at the time of filtering.

Comment: If you create a Min and Max value from the filter value entered, with min == -.01 that amount and max == +.01 you can use `number  >= min AND number < max`.  A few extras may sneak in, but it seems to work ok because it treats the numerc data in numeric terms